# Font Awesome class "fa-check" is not displaying check mark

Tags: css, html, font-awesome

I have a simple html page using font awesome css. Can anyone see why my font awesome check mark is not displaying, I cannot get the check mark to display and I cannot seem to figure out why. [image: font awesome check error]

I am using the `.min.css` link in my `<Head>` as such:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>LoopLAB Theme</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
```

When I want to inject it into a `<i>` element in the DOM, I simply use this:

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

As you can see above, the check mark does not display. Do you see anything obvious that I am doing wrong? This seems like a beginner's error but I can't find the problem.

Comment: and yo are sure the CSS file exist ? you can access it ?

Comment: Can you confirm, beyond a reasonable doubt, that the fontawesome css file is being loaded? At a glance, it looks like it isn't. For the sake of troubleshooting, try using an external CDN library instead to verify if this is the case. Check your DevTools console for any 404 errors (file cannot be found) as well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question should contain [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'm going to go out on a limb and say with 99.99% certainty that this is because your CSS file is not being loaded. Whether that's because of an incorrect path, filename etc. is to be seen. In Google Chrome hit _F12_ and click the _Network_ tab, any errors?

Comment: Looks good, so the problem must be somewhere else in your CSS. Or the route to your CSS is wrong. Or something. Can't really do mentalism. Please post a link

Comment: Font awesome or Font awesome5?

Comment: Are you sure href path is right, after typing href="", select .. and then navigate to the right path of the css. If it is already correct, please ignore.

Comment: yes, the font-awesome file exists in the same folder as the bootstrap and style.css folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your CSS. There are a few ways you can do that!

1. Simply check if font-awesome.min.css is indeed under your CSS folder. If it is, check your folder structure. Can your HTML access this folder using css/font-awesome.min.css? The CSS folder must be a child from the folder you are currently storing your HTML file. Finally, are you using the latest version of font-awesome-min.css? This specific icon might not be included in your CSS file if it's an older version.
2. Inspect your site using your favorite browser inspect tool and locate your CSS file on inside the inspector. Clicking on it should open your CSS code. The code should be minified. If there is nothing inside of it or some kind of error your website is failing to find your file on your server or computer.

Plus you can also add from a CDN, for example, https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css and import directly to your code.

Comment: Oddly, when I add the cdn, it works just fine. I checked the font-awesome.min.css file itself and everything is in there and minimized as expected. I loaded everything using npm and the version showing in the min (and package.json) file is 4.7.0. So, the file path looks correct, the version looks correct, the file itself contains the appropriate info...I'm at a loss. I'm going with the cdn solution right now, but there has to be another reason the file-->filepath method isnt working. Thanks.